# $\operatorname{Hom}(L, \operatorname{Hom}(M,N)) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(M, \operatorname{Hom}(L,N))$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, tensor-products

Let $L, M,N$ be three $A$-modules, $A$ a commutative ring. Show that $$\operatorname{Hom}_A(L, \operatorname{Hom}_A(M,N)) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_A(M, \operatorname{Hom}_A(L,N))$$

I know that, by adjunction of the functors $\operatorname{Hom}_A(-,M)$ and $M \otimes_A -$, we have $\operatorname{Hom}_A(L, \operatorname{Hom}_A(M,N)) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_A(L \otimes_A M,N)$. As $A$ is commutative, $L\otimes_AM \cong M \otimes_A L$. But in general, the functor $\operatorname{Hom}_A(-,N)$ is not exact, so we don't have $\operatorname{Hom}_A(L \otimes_A M,N) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_A(M \otimes_A L,N)$. Any suggestions?

Comment: If $L \otimes_A M \cong M \otimes_A L$ as $A$-modules, then Hom out of each is the same functor. It has nothing to do with exactness of Hom, does it?

Comment: Exactness of $\operatorname{Hom}_A(\_,N)$? If $F \colon \mathscr C \to \mathscr D$ is a functor, and $X$ and $Y$ are two isomorphic objects in $\mathscr C$, then $F(X) \cong F(Y)$ in $\mathscr D$. That’s because if $f \colon X \to Y$ is an isomorphism, then $F(f^{-1}) \circ F(f) = F(f^{-1} \circ f) = F(\operatorname{id}_X) = \operatorname{id}_{F(X)}$ and similarly $F(f) \circ F(f^{-1}) = \operatorname{id}_{F(Y)}$; so, $F(f)$ is an isomorphism too.

Comment: Right! I was thinking too hard on this one, I guess!

Answer (score 2):

You can define an explicit isomorphism $$f:\mathrm{Hom}_A(L,\mathrm{Hom}_A(M,N)) \to \mathrm{Hom}_A(M,\mathrm{Hom}_A(L,N))$$ by the formula
$$f(\phi)(m)(\ell)=\phi(\ell)(m) \quad \hbox{for $\phi \in \mathrm{Hom}_A(L,\mathrm{Hom}_A(M,N))$, $m \in M$, and $\ell \in L$.}$$ The inverse is obtained by symmetry, interchanging the roles of $L$ and $M$.